# Changing TkInter Scale won't update label "bg"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
slowColor = (255,0,255)

window = Tk()
window.title = 'Mouse Tracker'

label1 = Label(window, text='Slow Color')
label1.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=5)
label2 = Label(window, bg='#%02x%02x%02x' % slowColor)
label2.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=2, columnspan=9, sticky=NW+SE)
label3 = Label(window, text='R')
label3.grid(row=4, column=2)
label4 = Label(window, text='G')
label4.grid(row=4, column=5)
label5 = Label(window, text='B')
label5.grid(row=4, column=8)
slider1 = Scale(window, from_=255, to=0)
slider1.grid(row=5, column=2, rowspan=6)
slider2 = Scale(window, from_=255, to=0)
slider2.grid(row=5, column=5, rowspan=6)
slider3 = Scale(window, from_=255, to=0)
slider3.grid(row=5, column=8, rowspan=6)
label2.config(bg='#%02x%02x%02x' % (slider1.get(), slider2.get(), slider3.get()))
```

What's supposed to happen is that changing the value of one of the sliders, should change the "bg" color of label2.  But that isn't happening.  Label2 remains static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Changing TkInter Scale won't update label “bg”"*

That is false. The `Scale` widgets you have have the value of 0, and you configure the `label2`'s background to their values at the time that they are 0, thus the label is black, as `'#000000'` is black.

In order to dynamically update something whenever a `Scale`'s value is changed, use `command` option in `Scale`:

```
def update():
    global label2, slider1, slider2, slider3
    label2.config(bg='#%02x%02x%02x' % (slider1.get(), slider2.get(), slider3.get()))

...

slider1['command'] = lambda scale_value: update()
slider2['command'] = lambda scale_value: update()
slider3['command'] = lambda scale_value: update()
```

---

Alternatively, command already passes `Scale`'s value but it may yield extra overhead in this case.

Comment: Alright, thanks!  I always do hate calling global variables though.  It just seems clumsy.

Comment: @BenParker You don't _have_ to pass them explicitly as globals. Regular pass is a bit unclear, hence I skipped it for clarity. Further note that the variables that are only read needn't be declared global, so in fact the `Scale` objects' declarations can be skipped. Even further all widgtes have an internal reference in the underlying Tcl interpreter so you can even ditch the declaration for the `Label` that is modified; at which point it would harm readability though, IMHO. As I think `label2` is as global as they come.